# Using 'typeof' with a template literal does not work as a type

Tags: typescript

It seems like Typescript doesn't accept Template Literals with typeof.

For example :

```js
const bar = 'bar';
const foo = `foo-${bar}`; // 'foo-bar'

const a: typeof foo = 'not foo-bar'; // No error


const foobar = 'foo-bar';

const b: typeof foobar = 'not foo-bar'; // Error
```

`a` should throw an error like `b` is doing, right?

And it also doesn't throw any error with : `'foo-'.concat(bar)` and `'foo-' + bar`.

Maybe there is another way of doing so?

Comment: `typeof foo` is just `string`, so there's no error.  The compiler does not lift string manipulation to the type level.  In particular, [template literals are not evaluated at the type level](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33757).

Comment: @jcalz Right, so there is no way I can use typeof to do a "String Literal Types" using any kind of string concatenation?

Comment: Correct, this is currently impossible.  Sorry.

Comment: Alright, thanks you anyway!